# Absolute Div top position changed while zoom ( Ctrl + ) in chrome browser

Tags: css, html, google-chrome

I have problem with absolute positioning DIV over the table element. I have a DIV that’s set the position absolute and set the top position to display the exact place. Now what happened in chrome browser while zooming (ctrl +) the DIV position has been changed at zoom level 125, 150, 175 ... etc.  But Zoom level 100,200, 300… (Multiple of 100) it’s displayed the same position. The problem was other than the multiple of 100 zoom level the DIV position changed. How can I fix this issue ?
I have created the sample page in jsfiddle  - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mJcsb/5/)  . please run the page in chrome browser and zoom the browser ( ctrl + ) the red color DIV position will be change, this is the issue. I really hope someone find a solution for this.

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
<table width="700px" class="custom">
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div>
    <div class="apptest">    </div></div>
```

CSS :

```
    table
{
border-collapse:collapse;
}
.custom tr td
        {
            height:20px;
            border:1px solid;
           background-color:White;
        }

.container {
    position: relative;
}
        .apptest
        {
            height:70px;
            width:400px;
            position:absolute;
            top:185px;
            left:0px;
            background-color:Red;
        }
```

Link : http://jsfiddle.net/mJcsb/5/

Answer (score 0):

Use a container with a style like this;

```
.Container {
    margin-right: auto; 
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to debate whether tables are a poor choice or not these times. But an absolute positioning here is a pretty bad idea.

I don't know what you have to do and what is your aim, but you could have a different (and probably better) solution using divs; in that case, a div containing your "red" div would just.. contain it, heh!

If you want to go anyway with absolute positioning and tables, be aware that this is a dirty solution and could break anytime. In that case, I'd suggest you to go with percentage-based absolute positioning, so that the box flows with the zoom (that is, by the way, difficult to predict and normalize in every browser).

i.e.

```
.apptest
    {
        height:70px;
        width:400px;
        position:absolute;
        top:61.2%;
        left:0px;
        background-color:Red;
    }
```

A fork of you fiddle with percentage for absolute positioning **(POOR SOLUTION WARNING HERE)**: http://jsfiddle.net/U4TGd/

Keep in mind that, again, this **is a bad solution** and mixing percentages and pixels in often a bad idea. If you have time or possibility, convert your table-based design and use divs instead of tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Its not the div position which was changing, the one which our eye relates the div position was changing(in this case the table border of each cell).

I found out this with some testing,

use this css to know that the absolute position div is in exact position.

```
.custom tr td {
    height:20px;
    border:0px solid;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    height:185px;
    background:#0F6;
}
.apptest {
    height:70px;
    width:400px;
    position:fixed;
    top:185px;
    left:0px;
    background-color:Red;
}
```

So you have no problem with absolute positioning DIV, but maybe chrome rendering the table cells differently.